# Intersections/Reunions of power sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let $P_i$ be the power set of $A_i=\{1,2,3,\cdots ,i\}$. What is:
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}(P_{i+1} - P_{i})$$

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}(P_{i+1} - P_{i})$$

The problem asks you to find those two sets separately.
I know that $P_i$ is:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        \{\} & \{1\} & \{2\} & \{\cdots \} & \{i\} \\
        \{1,2\} & \{1,\cdots \} & \{1,i\} & \{\cdots ,\cdots\} & \{i-1,i\} \\
        \{1,2,3\} & \{1,2,\cdots \} & \{1,2,i\} & \{\cdots ,\cdots,\cdots \} & \{i-2,i-1,i\} \\
        \{1,2,\cdots ,k\} & \{1,2,\cdots ,k+1\} & \{1,2,\cdots ,k+2 \} & \{1,2,\cdots ,k+p\} & \{1,2,3,\cdots ,i\} \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

If $$P_{i+1} - P_{i}=\{\{i+1\},\{i,i+1\},\{i-1,i,i+1\},\{i-k,i-k+1,\cdots ,i,i+1\},\{1,2,3,\cdots ,i+1\}\}$$,
what are the sets?

Comment: Every set in $P_{i+1}$ containing $i+1$. There are $2^i$ of them, since for every set $A\in P_i$ we get a set $A\cup\{i+1\}\in P_{i+1}$ by adjoining the element $i+1$

Answer (score 1):

Proceed steop by step: $P_{i+1}-P_i$ is the set of subsets of $A_{i+1}$ that are not subsets of $A_i$, i.e. the set of subsets of $A_{i+1}$ that contain $i+1$. Then for $n>1$ the intersection is empty. In fact, this follows without speciifcally looking into the definition of the $P_i$ because 
$$ \bigcap_{i=1}^n(P_{i+1}-P_i)\subseteq (P_3-P_2)\cap(P_2-P_1)\subseteq (P_3-P_2)\cap P_2=\emptyset$$
What happens if $n=1$?

For the union we see immediately that it must be in $P_{n+1}$. If $X$ is a nonempty subset of $A_{n+1}$ let $k=\max X$. Do you see that $X\in P_k-P_{k-1}$? Do you see what simplified description of the union this allows?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: First try to discover that $B_i=P_{i+1} - P_i$ is. It is the set of all subsets in $P_{i+1}$ which do not appear in $P_i$, meaning the set of all subsets of $A_{i+1}$ which are not subsets of $A_{i+1}$. How would you quickly describe this set?